# Analytical calculation of control input for given system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

In the equations given below is it possible to calculate $u$ analytically to drive system from the initial condition of $x_{1} = 5$ ,$x_{2} = 0$ to the equilibrium point in the origin $x_{1} = 0$ ,$x_{2} = 0$?

$$(1) \qquad \dfrac{\mathrm{d} x_{1}}{\mathrm{d} t} = x_{2}$$
$$(2) \qquad \dfrac{\mathrm{d} x_{2}}{\mathrm{d} t} = u$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\1 \end{bmatrix}u,$$

in which $\boldsymbol{x}=\left[x_1,x_2 \right]^T$

Using full state feedback with $u = -k_1x_1 -k_2x_2$ we obtain the closed loop system
$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-k_1 & -k_2 \end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}.$$

The eigenvalue equation of the closed-loop system is given by

$$\chi(s)=s^2+k_2s+k_1.$$

By the Hurwitz criterion for quadratic polynomials, we can guarantee asymptotic stability of the closed-loop system if $k_1$ and $k_2$ are both positive but not zero. Independent from your initial conditions the system will converge to the equilibrium point in the origin for $t\to \infty$. Only if we start at the origin we will not take infinitely long to reach the origin. Another way to arrive at the origin is to use a nonlinear control law (see time optimal control and the theorem of Feldbaum for time optimal control of linear systems with constraints on the control inputs. This is sometimes called Bang-Bang-Control)

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I have a question, the input has to be function of states or it could just be constant or function of time in some cases?

Comment: Normally when we talk about a control law the control input $\boldsymbol{u}$ is always a function of the states $\boldsymbol{x}$. If $\boldsymbol{u}(t)$ then we might get a solution that is driving the initial condition to the equilibrium point. The problem is, that this solution is not feasible in real systems, as soon as you are a little bit out of sync or do not apply the correct control input you could land anywhere else in the state-space but not in the desired final state. There is a good example for that in the book of Eduardo Sontag on mathematical control theory.

Comment: You do not need nonlinear control to drive it to zero in finite time. For example you could use Pontryagin maximum principle with terminal constraints, which for linear systems has linear dynamics in the state and co-state.

Comment: @Kwin Van der Veen: Could you cite the resulting linear control law that drives the system to the equilibrium point in finite time? The constraint sounds like something nonlinear.

Comment: Given $\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$, $x(0)=x_0$, $x(T)=x_T$ and cost to be minimized $\int_0^Tx^TQx+u^TRudt$ you get the following optimal dynamics $\dot{z}=Mz$ with $u=-R^{-1}B^T\lambda$, $z=[x^T\ \lambda^T]^T$ and$$M=\begin{bmatrix}A&-BR^{-1}B^T\\-Q&-A^T\end{bmatrix}.$$The constraint $x(T)=x_T$ can be satisfied by solving for $\lambda(0)$ such that the top half of $z(T)=e^{MT}z(0)$ equals $x_T$. By defining$$e^{MT}=\begin{bmatrix}E_{11}&E_{12}\\E_{21}&E_{22}\end{bmatrix}$$then it follows that $x(T)=E_{11}x(0)+E_{12}\lambda(0)$, so $\lambda(0)=E_{12}^{-1}(x(T)-E_{11}x(0))$, which is all linear in $x$.

Comment: For example if you use the system from the question with $T=2$, identity for $Q$ and $R$ you get [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mQtzqujF7vMcG16wrXGFItnQQjiPP4I5/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: This would be equivalent to using finite horizon LQR, but then you also need to solve $\dot{P}=-A^TP-PA-Q+PBR^{-1}B^TP$ backwards in time with $u=-R^{-1}B^TPx$ and $P(T)$ infinity large in order to ensure $x(T)=0$. The dynamics for $P$ would indeed be nonlinear, but the control policy is still linear in $x$.